# Retrive all Google + users with their skills in the domain

Tags: google-app-engine, google-plus

Is it possible to get all the Google plus users of a particular domain with their skills and other details on profile. I tried with the below code

```
       Plus.People.List listPeople = plus.people().list(
            "me", "visible");
           listPeople.setMaxResults(5L);

             PeopleFeed peopleFeed = listPeople.execute();
             List<Person> people = peopleFeed.getItems();


          while (people != null) {
          for (Person person : people) {
            System.out.println(person.getDisplayName());
             }

    // We will know we are on the last page when the next page token is
    // null.
    // If this is the case, break.
    if (peopleFeed.getNextPageToken() == null) {
            break;
    }

    // Prepare the next page of results
    listPeople.setPageToken(peopleFeed.getNextPageToken());

    // Execute and process the next page request
    peopleFeed = listPeople.execute();
    people = peopleFeed.getItems();
```

}

But the 
                       plus.people().list("me", "visible");

take only two parameters "connected" and "visible" which will not solve the purpose. Does any one has a better idea ?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to combine the [Admin SDK Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/) with the Google+ Domains API to achieve what you want to do.

First you [retrieve the list of users](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list) via the Directory API, and you can then use the Google+ Domains API to retrieve more profile information for each user.

A while back I did a sample in PHP that uses this approach: https://github.com/gde-plus/gplus-domains-directory-sample-php

Comment: But the followingfunction only takes name as input , Is there a possibility to pass user email address and get all the profile details ? Plus.People.Search searchPeople = plus.people().search("Bipin");

Comment: In the Admin SDK you also get the User ID which you can use with plus.people().get(id);

Comment: There are people who do not have Google Plus profile in our organization and am trying the below code to validate                 Person profile = plus.people().get(test.getId()).execute();  and then checking by profile.isEmpty() which is not working. Do you have a better suggestion for validating

Comment: @user3223016 I think it would be good to ask that as a separate question, thanks.

Comment: The integrating with Admin SDK is working but it is crossing the maximum execution time. It is looping all ten thousand records. Do we have a Google Plus API to search for profile information ?